# ShareLinkTask instansiate a new page?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my browser app, I noticed when `ShareLinkTask` is called, the app's `MainPage()` is called again. How do I make sure the app does not navigate to the new instance of the `MainPage` when returning from `ShareLinkTask`?

The reason I want the original page is that the app has to remember the LayoutRoot grid on that page in order to display an UI animation. But since the new LayoutRoot grid is a different instance, the animation is not running once the app return from `ShareLinkTask`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`ShareLinkTask` is one of the Launchers. Your application will be `Deactivated` when you use a Launcher and go into Dormant or Tombstoned mode. In the first case the MainPage constructor would not be called again after returning from Launcher, only the OnNavigatedTo method. To prepare for the second case, save the state of the animation in OnNavigatedFrom and read the saved state in OnNavigatedTo. Read more about Tombstoning, starting with [Activation and deactivation best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [How to preserve and restore page state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

[More about Launchers and Choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769542%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)